# Iterative in-place quicksort

Tags: python, sorting, iteration, quick-sort

I have implemented an iterative in-place quicksort algorithm in Python, which by default selects the pivot as the last element:

```
def quicksort(array):
    """
    Sorts an array of integers using the quick-sort algorithm.

    :param array: the array to be sorted
    :type array: list<int>
    :return: the sorted array
    :rtype: list<int>
    """
    indexes_stack = list()
    idx = (0, len(array) - 1)
    indexes_stack.append(idx)
    for idx in indexes_stack:
        elem_idx = idx[0]
        pivot_idx = idx[1]
        while pivot_idx > elem_idx:
            pivot = array[pivot_idx]
            elem = array[elem_idx]
            if elem > pivot:
                array[pivot_idx] = elem
                array[elem_idx] = array[pivot_idx - 1]
                array[pivot_idx - 1] = pivot
                pivot_idx -= 1
            else:
                elem_idx += 1

        boundar_low = idx[0]
        boundar_high = idx[1]
        if pivot_idx > 1 and boundar_low < pivot_idx - 1:
            indexes_stack.append((boundar_low, pivot_idx - 1))
        if pivot_idx < len(array) -1 and pivot_idx + 1 < boundar_high:
            indexes_stack.append((pivot_idx + 1, boundar_high))

    return array

# Test the sorting function
counter = 0
while counter < 1000:
    test = [int(100 * random.random()) for i in xrange(15)]
    assert (quicksort(list(test)) == sorted(test)), test
    counter += 1
```

I've tested it with various inputs and it seems to be correct, but I wonder if it can become more efficient or clean.

Comment: Thanks for catching the bug, I re-written function and the testing code to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

The implied [any aspect of the code posted is fair game for feedback and criticism](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) justifies asking on CR even without an(y) explicit question. I'm taken against guessing what any piece of code is there for: ***Why*** another python quicksort? doesn't get answered *in the code*.
While the docstring looks [charming](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/documenting-source-code-in-pycharm.html), the parameter to `quicksort()` is over-specified: everything needed is "subscripting" to get&set *item*s and *comparable* items. (Numeric items could be deemed handy for picking as a pivot the mean value of several.)
*The code* mentions neither `iterative` nor `in-place`:
`quicksort()` should be *specified* to return its (ordered) parameter.

`clean`, like beauty, lies in the eye of the beholder - to mine, both are close regarding code. I like python for its ability to express things with minimum ado.
(I don't quite like `elem_idx`&`pivot_idx` - sometimes use `up`&`down`.)

In demonstration code, it seems to have grown conventional to factor out *partition*ing the current sequence from `quicksort()`.

*True*? The code doesn't use `indexes_stack` as a stack. As far as [`in-place` means o(n) space](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/80624/does-in-place-for-n-items-imply-space-dominated-by-n) (in addition to *output is where input used to be*), the implementation presented is *not* in-place.

*More efficient*? Sure -

- Space: handle the smallest partition first (with impeding *out-of-memory*, this is a *correctness* issue)
- Time:

  - choice of `pivot` is pivotal, using a value from either end of the partition disastrous for pre-ordered input.
  - [Hoare partition scheme instead of Lomuto](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm) - three-way if lots of repeated values are to be expected
  - don't bother with less than two items, better yet:
    use a different algorithm for small partitions
  - don't push the top-priority partition to immediately pop it

In stead of further ranting (keeping `elem`, `elem_idx` & `pivot_idx` for recognition value):

```
# non-recursive quicksort - re-inventing the wheel finger exercise 

# docs.python.org tutorial:
# To add an item to the top of the stack, use append()
class stack(list):
    ''' push() to add an item to the top of the stack '''
    push = list.append


# non-recursive quicksort
def quicksort(items):
    """
    Sort a sequence using the quick-sort algorithm.

    :param items: the sequence to be sorted
    :return: items, sorted
    """
    nItems = len(items)
    if nItems < 2:
        return items
    todo = stack([(0, nItems - 1)])
    while todo:
        elem_idx, pivot_idx = low, high = todo.pop()
        elem = items[elem_idx]
        pivot = items[pivot_idx]
        while pivot_idx > elem_idx:
            if elem > pivot:
                items[pivot_idx] = elem
                pivot_idx -= 1
                items[elem_idx] = elem = items[pivot_idx]
            else:
                elem_idx += 1
                elem = items[elem_idx]
        items[pivot_idx] = pivot

        lsize = pivot_idx - low
        hsize = high - pivot_idx
        if lsize <= hsize:
            if 1 < lsize:
                todo.push((pivot_idx + 1, high))
                todo.push((low, pivot_idx - 1))
        else:
            todo.push((low, pivot_idx - 1))
        if 1 < hsize:
            todo.push((pivot_idx + 1, high))
    return items


if __name__ == '__main__':
# run the sorting function
    from random import randint
    for _ in range(99):
        test = [str(randint(0, 100)) for _ in range(randint(15, 99))]
        assert (quicksort(test[:]) == sorted(test)), test
```